# Showing that an entire function $\,f$ is a constant function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function, satisfying
$$
\mathrm{Im}(\,f(z)) \gt \mathrm{Re}(\,f(z))^2 - 2,
$$ 
for all $z\in\mathbb C$.

How can I show that $f$ is constant?

Comment: Writ down question properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the function $g(z) = \exp(if(z))$. We have $$|g(z)| = \exp(-\operatorname{Im}(f(z))) < \exp(-[\operatorname{Re}(f(z))]^2 + 2) \le \exp(2).$$

So $g$ is bounded. Furthermore, $g$ is entire since $f$ is entire. By Liouville's theorem, $g$ is constant. Show that this implies $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, but a little different. Assume that the image of an entire function $f$ avoids some disc $|z-a| < r$. Then
$$
g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)-a}
$$
is bounded (why?) and entire. By Liouville's theorem $g$ is constant, and hence $f$ must be as well.